# Extract Images from iPhone Safari Cache?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to extract images from the iPhone Safari cache?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is short answer, you app runs in a sandbox and you can't interact in that way with any other apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would there be a way to do this via SSH and manually going to their respective directories?

Comment: Probably, but you will have to do this on a jailbroken phone.

Comment: My phone is jailbroken and I'm able to ssh into it. I'm just unsure as to how I would go about retrieving the cached images from it.